# Animating transitions from image array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm a newbie when it comes to jQuery and I'm fiddling around with a slider of sorts that loads images from a array and posts the result to a div. The way I have it set up it loads the image tag and image source and places it to an empty div. Now any animations in jQuery that I've seen what work in conjunction with an array have been formatted much differently. I should mention that I'm not looking for elegant, but just code that works.

Basically, is it possible to incorporate transitions with the way I'm doing it now? And if so, how? Nothing fancy, just a fade or swipe effect.

[jsFiddle so far](http://jsfiddle.net/txmt6a0x/)

```
 var imgArray = 
    ['<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/cf5">',
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/555">', 
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/f0f">', 
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/05b">']

    counter = -1;

    $('#nextimage').click(function () {
    counter = (counter + 1) % imgArray.length; 
    console.log(imgArray[counter]); 
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = (imgArray[counter]);
    });

    $('#previmage').click(function () {
    counter = (counter - 1); 
    console.log(imgArray[counter]); 
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = (imgArray[counter]);
    });
```

html

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider_wrapper">
      <div id="slider">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <div id="result1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="#" id="previmage"><img title="Previous Image" alt="prev image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/prev.png"></a>
        <a href="#" id="nextimage"><img title="Next Image" alt="next image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65639888/image/next.png"></a>
    </div>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}
.container{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dashed black;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background: black;  
}
.slider_wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    top:auto;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: white;
}

#slider{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
}
#slider img{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.nvgt{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: BLACK;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #84BAFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.1;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#footer img {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    height: 30px;
}

#footer:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

ul, menu, dir, html, body {
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: You should always look for elegant.

Comment: are u lookin for auto transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous and next button working properly with fade out effect

```
var imgArray = ['<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/cf5">',
            '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/555">',
            '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/f0f">',
            '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/05b">']

counter = -1;

function imgTransition() {
    $('#result1').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#result1').html(imgArray[counter]);
        $('#result1 > img').on('load', function() {
            $('#result1').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
};

function next() {
    counter = (counter + 1) % imgArray.length;
    console.log(counter);
    imgTransition();
};

next();

$('#nextimage').click(next);

$('#previmage').click(function() {
    if (counter == '0') {
        counter = imgArray.length;
    }
    counter = (counter - 1);
    console.log(imgArray[counter]);
    imgTransition();
});
```

[JSFIIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/sxjuc8rn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxjuc8rn/)</kbd>

```
var imgArray =
    ['<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/cf5">',
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/555">',
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/f0f">',
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/05b">'],

    counter = -1;
var animate = false;  //stopping invalid click during animation

function animatable() {
    $('#result1').slideUp(300, function() {
        $('#result1').html(imgArray[counter]);
        $('#result1 > img').on('load', function() {
            //$('#result1').fadeIn(500);
            $( '#result1' ).animate({
              height: "toggle"
            }, 1000 , function(){
                animate = false;
            });
        });
    });
};
function next(){
    if(!animate){
        animate = true;
    counter = (counter + 1) % imgArray.length;
    console.log(counter);
      $("#result1").fadeIn().html(imgArray[counter]);
    animatable();
    }
};

next();

$('#nextimage').click(next);

$('#previmage').click(function () {
    if(!animate){
        animate = true;
      if(counter=='0'){
        counter= imgArray.length;
      }
    counter = (counter - 1); 
    console.log(imgArray[counter]); 
      $("#result1").html(imgArray[counter]);
    animatable();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[update with animatable](http://jsfiddle.net/sxjuc8rn/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified in the post that I was looking for transition effects. Edited to reflect this.

Comment: Look at my answer now, you can add more animations

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to wait until the image has been loaded.

```
var imgArray = 
    ['<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/cf5">',
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/555">', 
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/f0f">', 
    '<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300/05b">']

counter = -1;

function imgTransition() {
    $('#result1').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#result1').html(imgArray[counter]);
        $('#result1 > img').on('load', function() {
            $('#result1').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
};

$('#nextimage').click(function () {
    counter = (counter + 1) % imgArray.length; 
    console.log(imgArray[counter]);
    imgTransition();
});

$('#previmage').click(function () {
    counter = (counter - 1); 
    console.log(imgArray[counter]); 
    imgTransition();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txmt6a0x/1/)

Comment: Once I have the karma to upvote I'll do so. No idea why it's down voted. Answered my question very well.

Comment: @GoldCoin No problem mate, I don't care about the downvotes. I was just wondering if I did something wrong. Glad I could help.